# WSO2 P.PaaS : Accessing the AS and other WSO2 products

Tags: wso2, application-server, paas, wso2-cloud, wso2-as

So I have got WSO2 P.PaaS installed and running. I want to deploy `.war` file to the Application Server. It seems the AS on P.PaaS does not accept `.war` file; but the stand-alone one does. See [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS510/Web+Applications). Also, I want to use the WSO2 products deployed into the PaaS. I am not sure what URL or port I should use. Is there a tutorial that I can use to experiment?

Sorry for the brevity, but, I am new to WSO2.

Answer (score 1):

What PPaaS version you have installed, 4.0.0 or from current master branch which is 4.1.0 milestone 1 version?

Here is the quick start guide [Quick start guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Quick+Start+Guide) .
You can access the management console as https://STRATOS_DOMAIN:9443/console.

Assuming you are using PP 4.0.0 version,

- Log into management console
- Go to cartridges page. There you can find the  available cartridges, you should find Application Server as a cartridge.
- Click on AS cartridge in order to subscribe for it. At subscribing process you would be asked a GIT repository URL.

After you subscribe, PP will clone what is in your GIT repository url in to Application server. So if you provide a url which has your web application, those application would be automatically deployed into the Application server. Here is a [sample GIT repository](https://github.com/sajhak/appserver2) , you can include your web apps under "webapps" folder.

There after if you modify your web apps (say web app version 2) and commit the changes to your repository, Stratos/PP automatically update Application server with the new web apps.

Since you have already deployed PP, you can have a loot at this [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngdhoxBjpZI) to see how you can deploy a web app

Comment: Got it. Let me try this and get back to you. Just for argument sake, can I get PP talk to some other repository as well? Is this 'transparent' to PP?

Comment: You can use any Git repository, with the folder structure as in sample repo. Your webapps(.war) should go to "webapps" directory.

Comment: @LahiruGamage my question was - does it have to be Git? Can I use my own 'file repository' or 'source control system'?

Comment: WSO2 Private PaaS onlys supports Git at the moment.